# Adding one day to a date field until the join is successful

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, join, conditional-statements

Not sure if the title describes it very well, but my problem is basically that I'm trying to join one table on to another by the date as well as a Product ID fields to be able to bring in the price assigned to that product on that day. One table is for sales history, and the other is a list of every product we have, with the updated prices for the day. The price table is simply 3 columns; ProdID, Date, Price. Every day when a new set of prices is generated, I add the new days data to the bottom of the Prices table, so ProdIDs will be duplicated numerous times for each day.

Our sales history table does not store the price at which the Product was sold at on the day, so we have to bring that value from the Price table with the full list of prices for each day, which is where the join to ProdID and Date comes in.

So far fairly straight forwards so far...

My problem comes from the fact that the the table with the updated prices for the day is only generated on work days, so I am left with 2 days of the week where there is no date and price to be able to join to sales made on the weekend, and so am left with blanks in the price column.

To get around this, I want the logic of the join to bring in the 'next available price'. E.g. If a sale was made on a Saturday or a Sunday, I want to pull in the price that was created on the Monday. Would this involve some sort of statement that adds a day on to the date until it can perform the join?

I am doing this all in MS Access.

Price Table:

`+---------+-------+------------+----------+
| ProdID  | Price |    Date    | Weekday  |
+---------+-------+------------+----------+
| 9999999 | £50   | 07/06/2016 | Thursday |
| 9999999 | £50   | 08/06/2016 | Friday   |
| 9999999 | £45   | 11/06/2016 | Monday   |
| 9999991 | £100  | 07/06/2016 | Thursday |
| 9999991 | £100  | 08/06/2016 | Friday   |
| 9999991 | £95   | 11/06/2016 | Monday   |
+---------+-------+------------+----------+`

Expected outcome of Sales table:

`+---------+------------+------------+----------+--+
| ProdID  | Sell Price |    Date    | Weekday  |  |
+---------+------------+------------+----------+--+
| 9999999 | £50        | 08/06/2016 | Friday   |  |
| 9999999 | £45        | 09/06/2016 | Saturday |  |
| 9999999 | £45        | 10/06/2016 | Sunday   |  |
| 9999999 | £45        | 10/06/2016 | Sunday   |  |
| 9999991 | £100       | 08/06/2016 | Friday   |  |
| 9999991 | £100       | 08/06/2016 | Friday   |  |
| 9999991 | £95        | 10/06/2016 | Sunday   |  |
+---------+------------+------------+----------+--+`

Many thanks.

Comment: Please add some sample data of input tables and expected result. Use http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Added some tables. As can be seen in the first table, a new price is generated every work day (sorted by ID), and can often be a repeat of the last price with no change. I need the sales table to use the price generated on the following working day. E.g. If a sale of ID 9999999 is made on the 9th-10th June (weekend) it would pickup the price created on the monday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution does not work with a join but with a sub select.

I assume that you have a SALES_HISTORY table as follows:

```
SALES_HISTORY
+---------+-------------+----------+
| ProdID  |     Date    | Weekday  |
+---------+-------------+----------+
| 9999999 |  07/06/2016 | Thursday |
| 9999999 |  08/06/2016 | Thursday |
| ...     |  ...        | ...      |
+---------+-------------+----------+
```

The SQL statement below first selects all columns of the sales history table and then selects the price of the product on the sales date or on the first avaliable date after the sales date.

```
SELECT ProdID,
       Date,
       Weekday,
       (SELECT Price
        FROM   PRICE_TABLE P
        WHERE  P.ProdID = S.ProdID
        AND    P.Date = (SELECT MIN(P2.Date)
                         FROM   PRICE_TABLE P2
                         WHERE  P2.ProdId = P.ProdID
                         AND    P2.Date >= S.Date))
FROM   SALES_HISTORY S;
```

(Please note that the SQL statement was typed into an editor and is therefore untested.)

Comment: Yes my sales table is more or less formatted as you have mentioned above. It has a few more columns but I am only including the essential ones at the moment. The weekday field was more just for reference and isnt in the original.

I have set this query running with your code, and Access is now working away at it. How long would you expect a query like this take to run? There are just under 1 million lines in the price table, and about 100k in the Sales one.

Comment: I cannot give an reasonable estimation of the duration. Still, given the complexity of the query and the number of rows in the tables, I presume that the query is not a matter of seconds. In this case, I would rather add the missing dates to the price table.

Comment: It ain't quick, but your code does indeed seem to work. Greatly appreciate your help! I believe the reason it's taking so long to run is it is having to run through the list multiple times for each ID. Would it be possible to index the tables to improve the speed? I have not really worked with indexing before so am a bit unsure on the process. Thanks again!

Comment: I have never worked on MS-Access, I can thus give only very general advice about the use of indexes. Here, indexes are recommended on columns that are used to join tables and on columns that are used in where constraints, in our case on the primary key columns and on the columns SALES_HISTORY.Date and PRICE.Date.

Comment: Your advice worked perfect Samuel, thank you for your help. Indexed, the report works flawlessly. How would I go about bringing in additional columns from the sub query? On top of the 'Price', I would like to bring in the 'Cost' which is in the column next to it in the 'Price_Table'. I tried to insert it in to your code, however it returned the following error: "You have written a sub query that can return more than one field without using the exists.........". Cheers